# SVG will only display locally, not live

Tags: html, browser, svg, dreamweaver

I have a SVG file which I have inserted into the html as so:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="1.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

This displays fine locally on all browsers, but none live.

Dreamweaver links me to the svg setup and if I copy that code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="219px" height="221px" viewBox="0 0 219 221" enable-background="new 0 0 219 221" xml:space="preserve">
<circle stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="109.036" cy="110.773" r="104.5"/>
<g id="Bullet_4_-_Down">
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="132.686,106.189 132.686,49.119 85.375,49.119 85.375,106.189 41.023,106.189 109.036,180.283 
        177.05,106.189  "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

In to the html file it works - however it looks very messy as I want to use this image multible times on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance that your web server is returning the SVG with an incorrect MIME type.  It should be `image/svg+xml`.  Check you web server configuration.

Comment: I think you are right on the server side - I will see if the IT team can help me with permissioning